# How do I get the ten reputation required to post an image for my app?

Tags: support, reputation, meta, obsolete

Funny that in order to enter and include a screenshot, you need ten reputation points. Go figure.

Comment: There. I gave you some.

Comment: Question is obsolete. See [my answer](http://stackapps.com/a/6987). Borderline off topic, even with this site being its own meta.

Answer (score 2):

You reach out and find a kind soul like https://stackapps.com/users/18/george-edison.

Comment: You're absolutely right!

Answer (score 2):

Good point - though some might argue that an app doesn't deserve a screenshot until it gets at least one upvote.

You have a valid concern though.

Answer (score 2):

If you associate your account on stackapps.com with your account on stackoverflow.com (for example), you automatically get 100 rep (that's why I'm on 101 at the moment :)

I believe you just click on your username at the top, then on the "accounts" tab.

Comment: only if you have 200 rep on the target site, which this user does not

Answer (score 0):

This reputation is no longer needed, to post images, as of about September 2013.
From [hairboat♦'s answer on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195927/148310):

> The restriction has therefore simply been removed on all sites except Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Ask Ubuntu and Super User.